# Perl CGI Javascript included but the alert is not happening

Tags: javascript, perl, cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';
use CGI qw(-debug);
use CGI ':standard';

print header(),
   start_html(-title => "OutSide File", -script   =>{-type=>"text/javascript",-src=>"javascript/javafile.js"}),
'<a href="#" onmouseOver="testfunc()"> mouse On </a>',
   end_html;
```

javafile.js is -

```
function testfunc(){
 alert("File")
}
```

The testfunc does not alert on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I created the HTML file with

```
perl test.pl >test.html
```

and opened the resulting file in Firefox and IE. The alert shows up perfectly.

Some issues, which might prevent the alert from happening

- Wrong directory hierarchy, `javafile.js` must be in a `javascript` subdirectory
- Javascript is suppressed by Noscript (Firefox) or disabled in the appropriate security zone (IE)

Comment: Olaf Thanks for the reply, the file is not test.pl but its required to be as test.cgi.I have put javafile.js in subdirectoy of javascript only.Even now the alert is not happening could you help me fix the same.

Comment: Do you see the "mouse on" text?

Comment: The mouse on text in debug mode shows the function name,might be the javascript file is not getting included.The source code shows the src as included in browser but does not alert, I tried different possibility to include still its not alerting.Could you please suggest

Comment: When you see the page, look if you can see javascript as well. Replace the uRL bar `/path/to/test.cgi` with `/path/to/javascript/javafile.js`. You should now see the javascript source.